Authentication cookie not included in the response header
I have a Blazor Web App that uses cookie authentication (not the built-in Identity). I'm trying to understand why when I authenticate the user directly in the application, the authentication cookie is included in the response header and shows up in the browser  cookies tab, but if I put the authentication logic, same code, behind an endpoint, then the cookie is not included anymore. To add more confusion, if I consume the endpoint from an external tool like Insomnia, http file or Postman, I can see the cookie in the response header, so it has to do with the client type.
This is Blazor Web App with global interactive auto, but I'm sure it doesn't matter here.
Login component runs static SSR mode:
Below the code that authenticate the user, it's the same used directly in the login component, and from the login endpoint(minimal api)
  var claims = new List<Claim>
  {
      new(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Email),
      new(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
      new(ClaimTypes.Role, "TestRole"),
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    claims,
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
     CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
     claimsPrincipal);

Cookie authentication config in Program.cs (Blazor server project)
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;        
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;        
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    }); 

Edit: CORS config
services.AddCors(options =>
  options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", corsPolicyBuilder =>
    corsPolicyBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()
      .AllowAnyMethod()
      .AllowAnyHeader());

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


Please try to use options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;, and tell us if it works or not in your side.

@JasonPan using SameSiteMode.None produce the same result.

Hi E-Bat, could you share your code about the CORS settings, make sure it is allowed to bring cookies(I mean AllowCredentials).

@JasonPan I've added my CORS config

Hi E-Bat, please add AllowCredentials I mentioned above for testing, tks~

@JasonPan adding  AllowCredentials didn't work. Currently my workaround is to get all user info in a response object from the api (name, email, roles), and call HttpContext.SignAsync from the login form whenever api response is 200.
